# Table date column formatting with google apps script html service

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am having problems figuring out basic table formatting.  I am hoping someone can see what I have and suggest a way of changing the outcome. My Google spreadsheet has 2 columns 'Number' and 'Date'.

My CodeGS looks like

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService
      .createTemplateFromFile('Index')
      .evaluate();
}

function getData() {
  return SpreadsheetApp
      .openById('1111111111111111111111')
      .getActiveSheet()
      .getDataRange()
      .getValues();

}
```

My Index.html

```
<? var data = getData(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<Style>
 body {
    font-family: arial;
  }

  table {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
  }

  table tr {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 5px;
  }

  table th, table td {
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left;
  }

  table th {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
  }
  </Style>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
<table>
   <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Number</th>
      <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>     
     <? for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) { ?>
        <tr>
          <? for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) { ?>
            <td><?= data[i][j] ?></td>
          <? } ?>
        </tr>
      <? } ?>

</table>

  </body>
</html>
```

When executed the Date column shows a value like 'Mon Dec 05 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST)'

In the spreadsheet and what I would like to see is something like '12/5/2016'

I am hoping someone can show me how to make this work

Regards,

Chris

Comment: Take a look at Javascript's [date formatting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleFormat)

Answer (score 0):

This is by no means an elegant solution but to completely control the date format for display I use the following:

```
var dateStr = 'Mon Dec 05 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST)';

function pad(n){
  var pad = "";  
  if(n < 10){pad = "0" + n}else{pad = n};  
  return pad;
}

function shortDate(dateString){

  var d = new Date(dateString);

  var curr_date = d.getDate();
  var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1;//zero indexed
  var curr_year = d.getFullYear();

  var shortDate = pad(curr_date) + "/" + pad(curr_month) + "/" + curr_year;

  return shortDate;

 }

 console.log(shortDate(dateStr));
```

This code will output a UK format date, you'll want to switch pad(curr_date) and pad(curr_month).

This does mean that you would have to write a table generating function to replace the way in which your table is generated currently as you need to handle the date values independently.

Comment: Sam thanks for the function.  I haven't successfully tested it yet. I'm still working on trying to split out the table generation like you suggested.  I'm a little slow here :-(